# C++, is there a way to (object.method(0,0) = 10) use assignment operator instead of an extra parameter?

Tags: c++, oop, methods, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I'm new to C++, and it's my first year in computer science and...
I just want to ask if... is there a way to make what i put in the title work?...

*To further explain what I mean, here is an example:*

```
    template <class dataType>
    class squareMatrix{
    private:
        int size_side;
        dataType *mainPtr;
    public:
        squareMatrix(int n){
            this->size_side = n;
            mainPtr = new dataType[n*n];
        }
   
        void index(int row, int column, dataType value){
            mainPtr[row+(size_side*column)] = value;
        }
    };
```

**so as you can see I need to use this method to manipulate an index in the matrix**

```
squareMatrix<int> obj(2);    // created a matrix of 2x2 size
obj.index(0,0,10);           // here is the method to store the number 10 in the 0,0 index
```

**And then my question, is there a way to make this into this?**

```
obj.index(0,0) = 10;
```

**Instead putting an extra parameter to the method is there a way to use the "=" or the assignment operator instead?**

Comment: In the case it was not intentional (for question readability for example), you should add a destructor for your `squareMatrix` class inside which you `delete[]` the `mainPtr` array. Otherwise every constructed `squareMatrix` would leak memory when destructed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can make `index` returning the reference to element, (like how [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) do,) e.g.

```
dataType& index(int row, int column) {
    return mainPtr[row+(size_side*column)];
}
```

then you can assign to the return value like

```
obj.index(0,0) = 10;
```